# Inno Setup: Program Folder not showing up in Start > All Programs

Tags: inno-setup, startmenu

I've been updating my Inno Setup installs and I'm running into a situation where the ***Program Folder*** is not showing up in the Windows 7 ***Start > All Programs***.

The wierd part is the program folder does exists in:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

The other weird thing is if I do the following:

[click] **Start**
[right click] **All Programs**
[click] **Properties**
[click] **Ok**

Go back to Start > All Programs the Program Folder shows up.

Can you think of anything that will cause this behavior?

**Inno Setup Script**

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Zilch Standard Trial"
#define MyAppVersion "4.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "ZilchWorks"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.zilchworks.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "zilchs40.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{D7C0A799-DDAF-49B4-951A-D3CD01D6AF6E}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppVerName={#MyAppName}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputDir=E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\Eval
OutputBaseFilename=zilchstd40-setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
PrivilegesRequired=none
CreateUninstallRegKey=yes
SignTool=kSign /d $q{#MyAppName}$q /du $q{#MyAppURL}$q $f
LicenseFile=E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\license.txt
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\{#MyAppExeName}

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"

[Files]
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\Eval\zilchs40.exe"; DestDir: {app}; 
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\history.txt"; DestDir: {app}; 
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\license.txt"; DestDir: {app}; 
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\readme.txt"; DestDir: {app}; 
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\sample1.zwf"; DestDir: {app}; 
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\sample2.zwf"; DestDir: {app}; 
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\sample3.zwf"; DestDir: {app}; 
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\zilchrps.dll"; DestDir: {app}; 
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\zilchstd.hlp"; DestDir: {app}; 
Source: "E:\New Software Install Packages\Zilch Standard 4.0\zilchstd.prf"; DestDir: {app}; 

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{app}\zilchs40.exe"; IconIndex: 0; 
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram, {#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{app}\zilchs40.exe"; IconIndex: 0; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Things I've tried:

1. System Restart (did not work)
2. Refresh Start Menu (did not work)

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe  
del %LOCALAPPDATA%\IconCache.db /a  
start explorer
```

Comment: How do you think we can say anything without seeing the InnoSetup script?

Comment: Did you try it one another machine?

Comment: Does system restart help?

Comment: I have not tried another machine. System restart did not help.

Comment: If you build an installer using the `Example1.iss` (from Inno Setup installation), does the "My Program" show in the Start menu?

Comment: Try another machine too.

Comment: Example1.iss installer behaves the exact same way. "My Program" missing until I click Start > All Programs > Properties > Ok

Comment: I'd say there's something wrong with your system then. What if you manually add a shortcut to the "Start Menu" folder?